# How to set up foreign key constraint in MySQL for cascading DELETE?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

Searched, but more confused now then when I started. I have 2 tables, `AlertsTable` and `AlertRecipientsTable`.

I'd like to add a cascaded delete that says when an `AlertRecipientID` is deleted (the person was removed), I want it to automatically delete all records in the `AlertsTable` that have that removed `AlertRecipientID`.

`AlertRecipientID` is a field in both tables. I still want to maintain ability to create an alert recipient without necessarily having an alert record set up for that recipient.

I'm confused on how to set up this constraint in MySQL. Have confirmed all my tables are configured as InnoDB and am using MySQL version 5.6.36-cll-lve.

**Example:**

AlertsTable:

```
AlertID AlertType   AlertName   AlertUserID AlertRecipientID AlertDateTimeAdded
1       1           Test        1           56               2018-01-07 14:29:39
```

AlertRecipientsTable:

```
 AlertRecipientID   AlertRecipientUserID    AlertRecipientFirstName AlertRecipientLastName
 56                 1                       John                    Doe
```

When I delete `John Doe` with `RecipientID` `56`, I'd like it to delete the entry in the `AlertsTable` named `Test`.

Comment: Hi. What did you search? Did you search a version of "i'd like to ..." without your particular names? Google my comments re googling questions. Did you google for & read any intros to FKs and the manual re FKs? Because this is explained in just about any such presentation. It's odd that you actually used "cascade" in your title yet you say you couldn't find out how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

```
ALTER TABLE AlertsTable
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AlertRecipientID)
REFERENCES AlertRecipientsTable (AlertRecipientID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This should work as you've described in your post. The foreign key constraint is on `AlertsTable` meaning no record can exist in that table with an `AlertRecipientID` that does not exist in `AlertRecipientsTable`, but you are free to have recipients in that table which do not have any entries within `AlertsTable`